# Javascript PubSub Scope Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, publish-subscribe

im having an issue with PubSub in Javascript.
im trying to figure out why $.subscribe is not printing the value. I assume its because of scope between $.publish and $.subscribe.

i would like to have other modules subscribe to the event. how would i do that?
i put an example on jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Fvk2G/

```
window.MQ = (function (window, document, undefined) {

    "use strict";

    function MQ() {

        testPubSub();

        function testPubSub() {
            $.publish("test");
        }
    }

    return MQ

})(this, this.document);

var mq = new MQ();

$.subscribe("test", function () {
    console.log("print value");
});
```

thanks

pete

Comment: Your test is calling your "publish" API *before* it sets up any subscriptions.

Comment: Also, there is no need for the `new` keyword in your example. You're not building an object from a constructor, just calling a function.

Answer (score 1):

You've set up a system that uses jQuery event handling for relaying messages, which is not in itself a bad idea. If you expect that it will save events that were triggered and report them to subsequent "subscribers", however, you've made an incorrect assumption about the semantics of the event mechanism. If a tree falls in the forest, the forest doesn't retain the sound until your hiking party arrives. Similarly, an event that's triggered with no listeners is just forgotten.

If you move your code that creates the "MQ" to *after* the subscription is done, then it works fine.

Comment: @KonstantinK thanks :)  I did it too but I didn't bother to save it.